# Creating an object from looping through an array of objects with a nested array. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, push

I am having trouble looping through an array within and object inside of an array and pushing those names into my result array. I know how to create new properties inside of my result object, but in order to do that, I need to get through pushing names into my created names array. Maybe I am not looping through it correctly.

```js
var students = [{
    name: 'joe',
    color: 'blue',
    age: 13,
    height: 61,
    "favorite hobbies": ['drawing', 'sports', 'swimming'],
    birthday: '1/12/1992'
  },
  {
    name: 'dave',
    color: 'red',
    age: 14,
    height: 60,
    "favorite hobbies": ['swimming', 'biking', 'hiking'],
    birthday: 'January 29, 1992'
  },
  {
    name: 'sally',
    color: 'yellow',
    age: 13,
    height: 64,
    "favorite hobbies": ['biking', 'singing', 'dancing']
  },
  {
    name: 'jane',
    color: 'white',
    age: 12,
    height: 58,
    "favorite hobbies": ['dancing', 'swimming', 'drawing']
  },
  {
    name: 'kayla',
    color: 'blue',
    age: 14,
    height: 62,
    "favorite hobbies": ['hiking', 'sports', 'drawing']
  },
];
// findHobbies, given an array of student objects, returns:
// an object containing three properties:
// hobby
// the targeted hobby
// students
// array of student names that match target hobby
// averageAge
// average age of students that match target hobby

var findHobbies = function(arr, target) {
  var result = {};
  result.hobby = target;
  // result.averageAge = 
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var names = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < arr[i]['favorite hobbies'].length; k++) {
      // console.log(arr[i]['favorite hobbies'][k])
      if (arr[i]['favorite hobbies'][k] === target) {
        array.push(arr[i].name);
      }
      console.log(array)
    }
  }
}


console.log(findHobbies(students, 'swimming'));
/*
     should return: 
     {
       hobby: 'swimming',
        students: ['joe', 'dave', 'jane'],
       averageAge: 13
     }


    */
```

Comment: What is `array`?

Comment: I meant to type names array.

Answer (score 0):

You should be pushing the student names onto `result.students`, which you can initialize with an empty array.

Use another variable to hold the total age of all the matching students. Add the ages to this, then calculate the average at the end.

```js
// findHobbies, given an array of student objects, returns:
// an object containing three properties:
// hobby
// the targeted hobby
// students
// array of student names that match target hobby
// averageAge
// average age of students that match target hobby

var findHobbies = function(arr, target) {
  var result = {
    hobby: target,
    students: [],
    averageAge: 0
  };
  var total_age = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < arr[i]['favorite hobbies'].length; k++) {
      if (arr[i]['favorite hobbies'][k] === target) {
        result.students.push(arr[i].name);
        total_age += arr[i].age;
      }
    }
  }
  if (result.students.length > 0) {
    result.averageAge = total_age / result.students.length;
  }
  return result;
}

var students = [{
    name: 'joe',
    color: 'blue',
    age: 13,
    height: 61,
    "favorite hobbies": ['drawing', 'sports', 'swimming'],
    birthday: '1/12/1992'
  },
  {
    name: 'dave',
    color: 'red',
    age: 14,
    height: 60,
    "favorite hobbies": ['swimming', 'biking', 'hiking'],
    birthday: 'January 29, 1992'
  },
  {
    name: 'sally',
    color: 'yellow',
    age: 13,
    height: 64,
    "favorite hobbies": ['biking', 'singing', 'dancing']
  },
  {
    name: 'jane',
    color: 'white',
    age: 12,
    height: 58,
    "favorite hobbies": ['dancing', 'swimming', 'drawing']
  },
  {
    name: 'kayla',
    color: 'blue',
    age: 14,
    height: 62,
    "favorite hobbies": ['hiking', 'sports', 'drawing']
  },
];


console.log(findHobbies(students, 'swimming'));
/*
     should return: 
     {
       hobby: 'swimming',
        students: ['joe', 'dave', 'jane'],
       averageAge: 13
     }


    */
```

Answer (score 0):

For an alternate solution, you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve the result

```js
var students = [
  {
    name: "joe",
    color: "blue",
    age: 13,
    height: 61,
    "favorite hobbies": ["drawing", "sports", "swimming"],
    birthday: "1/12/1992",
  },
  {
    name: "dave",
    color: "red",
    age: 14,
    height: 60,
    "favorite hobbies": ["swimming", "biking", "hiking"],
    birthday: "January 29, 1992",
  },
  {
    name: "sally",
    color: "yellow",
    age: 13,
    height: 64,
    "favorite hobbies": ["biking", "singing", "dancing"],
  },
  {
    name: "jane",
    color: "white",
    age: 12,
    height: 58,
    "favorite hobbies": ["dancing", "swimming", "drawing"],
  },
  {
    name: "kayla",
    color: "blue",
    age: 14,
    height: 62,
    "favorite hobbies": ["hiking", "sports", "drawing"],
  },
];
// findHobbies, given an array of student objects, returns:
// an object containing three properties:
// hobby
// the targeted hobby
// students
// array of student names that match target hobby
// averageAge
// average age of students that match target hobby

function findHobbies(arr, hobby) {
  const accumulator = {
    hobby,
    students: [],
    averageAge: 0,
  };
  const result = students.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { name, age, "favorite hobbies": sHobby } = curr;
    if (sHobby.includes(hobby)) {
      acc.students.push(name);
      acc.averageAge += age;
    }
    return acc;
  }, accumulator);
  result.averageAge /= result.students.length;
  return result;
}

console.log(findHobbies(students, "swimming"));
```